# How can I add/delete items from a ListView upon input from user?

Tags: java, listview, javafx, combobox

So I have the following `ListView`:

```
ObservableList<String> numList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "1","2","3"
        );
```

I want to be able to change the items within the `ListView` based on what the user selects in a `ComboBox` previously.

Say the user wants 7 items instead of the default 3 that I have. Then, the code would appear:

```
ObservableList<String> numList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "1","2","3","4","5","6","7"
        );
```

Is there any way to do this or do I have to create multiple `ListView`s and use whichever one I need based on the users input?

Comment: Did the proposed solution work? If so, mark the answer complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same `ListView`. You do not even need to replace the `items` list, you could just modify the existing items.
BTW: I recommend using `Integer` as type parameter in this case:

```
ComboBox<Integer> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(1, 3, 5, 7));
ObservableList<Integer> numList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ListView<Integer> listView = new ListView<>(numList);

ChangeListener<Integer> listener = (observable, oldCount, newCount) -> {
    int size = numList.size();
    int newSize = newCount == null ? 0 : newCount;
    if (size > newSize) {
        numList.subList(newSize, size).clear();
    } else {
        for (int i = size+1; i <= newSize; i++) {
            numList.add(i);
        }
    }
};

comboBox.valueProperty().addListener(listener);

// in case you assigned a initial value before
listener.changed(null, null, comboBox.getValue());
```

---

However you could also replace the items list of a existing `ListView` with a new one using `setValue`

```
ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
ComboBox<ObservableList<String>> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(...);
ChangeListener<ObservableList<String>> listener = (observable, oldList, newList) -> {
    if (newList == null) {
        newList = FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
    }
    listView.setItems(newList);
};
comboBox.valueProperty().addListener(listener);

// in case you assigned a initial value before
listener.changed(null, null, comboBox.getValue());
```